# Switch between outlook message window VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I am trying to switch between new email messages in outlook. My question is how would I reference outlook message that I want to view. My code below creates two email messages in outlook and display them. I now want to select myitem1 as the active window.

```
Sub email()
Dim myItem1 As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myitem2 As Outlook.MailItem

Set myItem1 = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set myitem2 = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

myItem1.Display
myitem2.Display

Application.Windows (myItem1)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you want to do further on; but whatever it is you can still use myitem1. and myitem2; for just displaying it again you can go for

myitem1.display

again; but you could also set the subject, the Sender, or whatever else.

Comment: This is one of those answers that was staring me in the face! Thanks for the help!